# T-SQL: GROUP BY, but while keeping a non-grouped column (or re-joining it)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, common-table-expression

I'm on SQL Server 2008, and having trouble querying an audit table the way I want to.

The table shows every time a new ID comes in, as well as every time an IDs Type changes

```
Record #    ID          Type    Date
1           ae08k       M       2017-01-02:12:03
2           liei0       A       2017-01-02:12:04
3           ae08k       C       2017-01-02:13:05
4           we808       A       2017-01-03:20:05
```

I'd kinda like to produce a snapshot of the status for each ID, at a certain date.  My thought was something like this:

```
SELECT
    ID
    ,max(date) AS Max

FROM
    Table

WHERE
    Date < 'whatever-my-cutoff-date-is-here'

GROUP BY
    ID
```

But that loses the Type column.  If I add in the type column to my GROUP BY, then I'd get get duplicate rows per ID naturally, for all the types it had before the date.

So I was thinking of running a second version of the table (via a common table expression), and left joining that in to get the Type.

On my query above, all I have to join to are the ID & Date.  Somehow if the dates are too close together, I end up with duplicate results (like say above, ae08k would show up once for each Type). That or I'm just super confused.

Basically all I ever do in SQL are left joins, group bys, and common table expressions (to then left join).  What am I missing that I'd need in this situation...?

Comment: Please add desired output for given sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use row_number()

```
select *  
from ( select *
            , row_number() over (partition by id order by date desc) as rn 
       from table 
       WHERE Date < 'whatever-my-cutoff-date-is-here'
     ) tt
where tt.rn = 1
```

Comment: I would guess because it's a code-only answer with no explanation.

Comment: Well, I upvoted you!  I don't have access to the necessary database until  tomorrow or the day after to test it, but I think this may be it...

Answer (score 0):

> I'd kinda like know how many IDs are of each type, at a certain date.

Well, for that you use `COUNT` and `GROUP BY` on Type:

```
SELECT Type, COUNT(ID)
FROM Table
WHERE Date < 'whatever-your-cutoff-date-is-here'
GROUP BY Type
```

Comment: That would end up including all the types, not just the most recent (for that ID) before the cutoff date - so it wouldn't be a snapshot.

Comment: It would also lose all the IDs - which I guess I wasn't explicit, but I want to keep - I'll edit my post to be better phrased, thanks!

Comment: Well, In that case I agree with Ivan's comment, you should include the desired results in your question. It's still not very clear what you want to get out of that sample data.

Comment: See my answer.  Question is not clear but I think the crux is lose the Type column.

Answer (score 0):

Basing on your comment under Zohar Peled answer you probably looking for something like this:

```
; with cte as (select distinct ID from Table where Date < '$param')
select [data].*, [data2].[count]
from cte
cross apply 
( select top 1 *
  from Table
  where Table.ID = cte.ID
  and Table.Date < '$param'
  order by Table.Date desc
) as [data]
cross apply
( select count(1) as [count]
  from Table
  where Table.ID = cte.ID
  and Table.Date < '$param'
) as [data2]
```